# Python request doesn't work, but curl request does

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am having some issues dealing with the `requests` library. I am debugging api calls through postman, and was able to get the following request to work there, but could not reproduce a successful request call in python. I was also able to get it to work in curl. I posted the relevant bits

Can anyone explain why

This curl request works

```
curl --request GET 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashboardbygeneralsplits?PlayerID=1628369&TeamID=0&MeasureType=Base&PerMode=PerGame&PlusMinus=N&PaceAdjust=N&Rank=N&LeagueID=00&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular+Season&PORound=0&Outcome=&Location=&Month=0&SeasonSegment=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&OpponentTeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&GameSegment=&Period=0&ShotClockRange=&LastNGames=0%0A' --header 'Host:  stats.nba.com' --header 'User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0' --header 'Accept:  application/json text/plain */*' --header 'Accept-Language:  en-USen;q=0.5' --header 'Referer:  https://stats.nba.com/' --header 'Accept-Encoding:  gzip deflate br' --header 'Connection:  keep-alive' --header 'x-nba-stats-origin:  stats' --header 'x-nba-stats-token:  true'
```

But this identical request in python does not

```
import requests

url = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashboardbygeneralsplits?PlayerID=1628369&TeamID=0&MeasureType=Base&PerMode=PerGame&PlusMinus=N&PaceAdjust=N&Rank=N&LeagueID=00&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular+Season&PORound=0&Outcome=&Location=&Month=0&SeasonSegment=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&OpponentTeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&GameSegment=&Period=0&ShotClockRange=&LastNGames=0"

headers = {
    'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json text/plain */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-USen;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip deflate br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 19, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jacob/src/nbapy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I have seen similar issues posted here before, but I couldn't find any that seemed applicable to my problem. Does anyone see a difference between the requests or could explain why these (seemingly) identical requests would fail?

Comment: Your Accept* headers look wrong to me. Shouldn't they be comma-separated lists?

Comment: @Rup the curl one has the same Accept headers, and I also tried making it into a comma-separated list with no luck

Comment: not sure if this is the case, but some websites (Linkedin is one of them) are using order of headers to detect scraping.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Can you verify that your Python code is using TLS 1.2+? If that's not it, I'd try making both requests in as verbose a mode as you possibly can, to try and see what exactly both clients are sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged it. This is a good question. Apparently, changing the
`'Accept': 'application/json text/plain */*'`  to `'Accept': 'application/json'` did the trick.

I ran the script changing it.

```
import requests

url = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashboardbygeneralsplits?PlayerID=1628369&TeamID=0&MeasureType=Base&PerMode=PerGame&PlusMinus=N&PaceAdjust=N&Rank=N&LeagueID=00&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular+Season&PORound=0&Outcome=&Location=&Month=0&SeasonSegment=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&OpponentTeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&GameSegment=&Period=0&ShotClockRange=&LastNGames=0%0A"

headers = {
    'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-USen;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Output:

```
200
{'resource': 'playerdashboardbygeneralsplits', 'parameters': {'MeasureType': 'Base', 'PerMode': 'PerGame', 'PlusMinus': 'N', 'PaceAdjust': 'N', 'Rank': 'N', 'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2020-21', 'SeasonType': 'Regular Season', 'PORound': 0, 'PlayerID': 1628369, 'Outcome': None, 'Location': None, 'Month': 0, 'SeasonSegment': None, 'DateFrom': None, 'DateTo': None, 'OpponentTeamID': 0, 'VsConference': None, 'VsDivision': None, 'GameSegment': None, 'Period': 0, 'ShotClockRange': None, 'LastNGames': 0}, 'resultSets': [{'name': 'OverallPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'LocationPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'WinsLossesPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'MonthPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'PrePostAllStarPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'StartingPosition', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}, {'name': 'DaysRestPlayerDashboard', 'headers': ['GROUP_SET', 'GROUP_VALUE', 'GP', 'W', 'L', 'W_PCT', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', 'PFD', 'PTS', 'PLUS_MINUS', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS', 'DD2', 'TD3', 'GP_RANK', 'W_RANK', 'L_RANK', 'W_PCT_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'BLKA_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PFD_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'PLUS_MINUS_RANK', 'NBA_FANTASY_PTS_RANK', 'DD2_RANK', 'TD3_RANK', 'CFID', 'CFPARAMS'], 'rowSet': []}]}
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an explanation to why this worked?

Comment: Probably the server is accepting only `application/json`. I assume the server is doing an equality check.

Comment: I tried with `application/json; charset=utf-8` also, it doesn't work

Comment: But what does curl do differently to prevent this error?

Comment: Even I'm looking for the answer.